# Finding integer index of python data frame after performing a logical operation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have tow integers 'high' and 'low'(both integer value,my entire data set is numbers, containing  int and float valued columns.) and a data frame named 'data' and I want to find out the **integer index** of rows which satisfies following condition:

**Condition**

1. If all the columns in the data frame deviates from both high and low then delete that entire row.

How i did was to check for each column and find the intersecting values , but  couldn't find appropriate way, kindly help.

Number of columns in the data read could vary hence my code should be dynamic.
My code :

```
li = {}
variables = list(data.columns.values)   
for x in variables :
    li[x] = []
le = len(variables)

for x in range(0,le):
    li[(variables[x])].append( data[~(data[(variables[x])]>credentials[(variables[x])]['low']) & (data[(variables[x])]<credentials[(variables[x])]['high']) ].index)

vals = li.values()
uniq  = set([vals[0]]) # this line shows error.

for lst in vals[1:]:
     uniq.intersection_update(lst)

result_rows  = list (uniq)

data.drop(data.index[result_rows])
```

I am trying to achieve the condition by selecting indexes of **data != deviating**
but getting an integer index seems to be the problem. Couldn't find any proper answers in net.

my 'li' dict looks like this

```
{u'Combed': [Int64Index([148, 159], dtype='int64')],
 u'OE': [Int64Index([], dtype='int64')],
 u'P': [Int64Index([], dtype='int64')],
 u'PCH': [Int64Index([126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145], dtype='int64')],
 u'PV': [Int64Index([32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 81, 85], dtype='int64')],
 u'V': [Int64Index([], dtype='int64')]}
```

Comment: What error do you see? If its `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, this is because you are passing a single integer into the `set` statement, when it expects an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) object. `vals[0]` is an integer, therefore, your for loop is only appending a single element to that list. If this is expected, and you want to pass a single element list to the set statement, you need to change it to `set([vals[0]])`.

Comment: @SiHa: sorry for the typo i entered exactly how u mentioned , i get the error saying "unhashable type:Int64Index", I need a way to find the integer of the index.

li[column] seems to have index values rather than its integer value.

Comment: @user3792799 : Is your final requirement to find out rows where all the values in that particular row are within low and high?